# Disjoint Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c

Written in C. The program seems to work fine but after the second reload it crashes but then when you try to run it again it allows you to use it. However, after a couple of times it displays the error message:
HEAP CORRUPTIN DETECTED: after Normal Block (#78)
Not sure how to fix the heap. I assume I am freeing the memory incorrectly or something to that sort.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system ("cls")
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct
{
    char make[100];
    char model[100];
    int yearBuilt;
    float cost;
}Automobile;

void addAuto(Automobile** a, int* eSize, int size);
int compareChars(const void* a, const void* b);
void displayAuto(Automobile** autos, int eSize);
void displayMenu();  //function prototypes
void freeMemory(Automobile** autos, int size);
char getChoice(char* option);
Automobile** loadAutos(int* eSize, int* size);
void myFlush();
void saveAutos(Automobile** autos, int eSize, int size);
void sortByCost(Automobile** autos, int eSize);
void sortByMake(Automobile** autos, int eSize);

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int eSize = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char option;
    Automobile** autos = NULL;
    autos = loadAutos(&eSize, &size);
    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\nHow many cars will you have (at the most)?: ");
        scanf("%i", &size); FLUSH;
        PAUSE;
        autos = calloc(size, sizeof(Automobile*));
        if (autos == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory! Exiting the program.\n");
            PAUSE;
            exit(-1);
        } // end of if statement
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            autos[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(Automobile));
            if (autos[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory! Exiting the program.\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    free(autos[j]);
                }
                free(autos);
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    do
    {
        getChoice(&option);
        switch (option)
        {
        case 'A': // Add an automobile
            if (autos[eSize] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory! Exiting the program.\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            addAuto(autos, &eSize, size);
            break;
        case 'D': // Display automobiles
            displayAuto(autos, eSize);
            break;
        case 'Q': // Quit program
            printf("Exiting program...\n");
            printf("Thank you for using the Automobile Inventory System!\n");
            printf("See you next time :)");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;
        } //Ends the switch and all the cases
        printf("\n");
    } while (option != 'Q');
    saveAutos(autos, eSize, size);
    freeMemory(autos, size);
    return 0;
} // end of main

void addAuto(Automobile** a, int* eSize, int size)
{
    if (*eSize == size)
    {
        printf("No room to add more automobile...it is full!\n");
        PAUSE;
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter Automobile make: ");
    scanf("%s", a[*eSize]->make);
    printf("Enter Automobile model: ");
    scanf("%s", a[*eSize]->model);
    printf("Enter Automobile yearBuilt: ");
    scanf("%i", &a[*eSize]->yearBuilt);
    printf("Enter Automobile cost: $");
    scanf("%f", &a[*eSize]->cost); FLUSH;
    *eSize += 1;
} // end addAuto

int compareChars(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char* arg1 = *(const char**)a;
    const char* arg2 = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(arg1, arg2);
} // end compareChars

void displayAuto(Automobile** autos, int eSize)
{
    char option;
    printf("\n[C]ost low to high");
    printf("\n[M]ake ascending order");
    printf("\n\tEnter any one option: ");
    scanf(" %c", &option); FLUSH;
    if (option == 'C' || option == 'c')
        if (eSize == 0)
        {
            printf("You have to add at least one car....\n");
            PAUSE;
        }
        else
        {
            sortByCost(autos, eSize);
            PAUSE;
        }
    else if (option == 'M' || option == 'm')
        if (eSize == 0)
        {
            printf("You have to add at least one car....\n");
            PAUSE;
        }
        else
        {
            sortByMake(autos, eSize);
            PAUSE;
        }
} // end displayAuto

void displayMenu()
{
    CLS;
    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    printf("*******Welcome to Santa's Car show!******************************\n");
    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    printf("[A]dd one automobile\n");
    printf("[D]isplay all automobiles\n");
    printf("     [C]ost low to high\n");
    printf("     [M]ake ascending order\n");
    printf("[Q]uit program\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
} // end of displayMenu

void freeMemory(Automobile** autos, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(autos[i]);
    }
    free(autos);
} // end freeMemory

char getChoice(char* option)
{
    displayMenu();
    scanf("%c", &*option); FLUSH;
    return toupper(*option);
} // ends getChoice function


Automobile** loadAutos(int* eSize, int* size)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("autos.bin", "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("No previous saved data...\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(size, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fread(eSize, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    // allocate memory for the array of pointers and the structs in a single step
    Automobile** autos = calloc(*eSize, sizeof(Automobile*));
    if (autos == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation of memory failed...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        autos[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(Automobile));
        if (autos[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation of memory at autos[%i] failed...\n", i);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // read the array of pointers and the structs from the file in a single step
    for (int i = 0; i < *eSize; i++)
    {
        if (fread(autos[i], sizeof(Automobile), 1, file) != 1)
        {
            printf("Failed to read data from file.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("Previous saved data has been loaded into the inventory array!\n");
    PAUSE;
    return autos;
}

void myFlush()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');
} // ends myFlush function

void saveAutos(Automobile** autos, int eSize, int size)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("autos.bin", "wb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file for writing.\n");
        return;
    }

    fwrite(&size, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fwrite(&eSize, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    // write the array of pointers and the structs to the file in a single step
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; i++)
    {
        fwrite(autos[i], sizeof(Automobile), 1, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
} // ends saveAutos

void sortByCost(Automobile** autos, int eSize)
{
    int temp = 0;
    float autoCost[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; i++)
    {
        autoCost[i] = autos[i]->cost;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < eSize; ++j)
        {
            if (autoCost[i] > autoCost[j])
            {
                temp = autoCost[i];
                autoCost[i] = autoCost[j];
                autoCost[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nAutomobiles are displayed from low to high in terms of cost: \n");
    for (int l = 0; l < eSize; l++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < eSize; k++)
        {
            if (autoCost[l] == autos[k]->cost)
                printf("$%.2f\t%s\t%s\t%i\n", autoCost[l], autos[k]->make, autos[k]->model, autos[k]->yearBuilt);
        }
    }
} // end sortByCost

void sortByMake(Automobile** autos, int eSize)
{
    qsort(autos, eSize, sizeof(Automobile*), compareChars);
    printf("\nAutomobiles are displayed A-Z: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%i\t$%.2f\n", autos[i]->make, autos[i]->model, autos[i]->yearBuilt, autos[i]->cost);
    }
} // end sortByMake
```

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Don't do this:  `#define FLUSH myFlush();`.   It's not giving you anything, it makes the code less readable, and has potential to cause lots of issues if not used in exactly the right way.

Comment: The code would be a lot simpler if `autos` was an array of of `Automobile` rather than an array of `Automobile*`.   What do `size` and `eSize` represent?  Perhaps add comment, or rename the variables.

Answer (score 3):

The code is mixing up the variables `size` and `eSize` in `loadAutos()` during the allocation of the pointer-array.

As far as I can tell, `size` is the capacity allocated for storing car information, and `eSize` is how many of the automobile-slots are actually *used*.

During the binary-save, the first integer written is `size` (capacity), then `eSize` (capacity-used).  Then `eSize` lots of `Automobile` structures are written to the file.

But during the load, the sizes are both read, and then an array of pointers `eSize` (capacity-used) is allocated, then for `size` (capacity) worth of pointers, an `Automobile` is allocated. Then `eSize` (capacity-used) lots of an `Automobile` loaded.

So running this this in our imaginations with 3 cars in 100 spaces:

- We save 100 spaces, being used only by 3 cars.

  - write 100
  - write 3
  - write 3 structures
- On load, we allocate an array of 3 car pointers, then allocate 100 cars into them (97 **more than** what we allocated)

  - read 100
  - read 3
  - allocate pointers for 3
  - allocate structures for 100
  - load 3 structures

You're overwriting the end of the `a` array in the load because you've confused eSize and size.   Writing past the end of blocks allocated on the heap causes Heap Corruption.

Use clean and concise variable names, not `a`, `size`, `eSize`.  It's "size" and "eSize" that allowed you to make this bug.

Name the variable what it represents, maybe something "autosCapacity" and "capacityUsed".

If this is an assignment, make sure you add comments or you will be marked down.